# Google Indexed sub pages in wordpress pagination in post

Tags: pagination, paginate-links, noindex, rel-canonical

I'm using WordPress Pagination in Post. So that users can view the same post in different parts.

Issue - Google is indexing all the subpages. How to resolve it? :/

http://example.com/post/ (original)

http://example.com/post/1 (first page of post)

http://example.com/post/2 (second page of post)

http://example.com/post/3 (Third page of post)

Removing each page manually is not possible as I'm using for almost every post.

How to make Google index just the first page of the post rather than indexing multiple pages of same post.

**Working Example** - Rd(dot)com (using wordpress as CMS)

You can see pagination in post with single url indexed in Google.

Comment: What's the problem here? If GoogleBot has access to the URL, and it's indexable, it will be. You might find some assistance in [this post](https://moz.com/ugc/seo-guide-to-google-webmaster-recommendations-for-pagination). Also [this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html).

Comment: With yoast seo you can set "noindex" to paginated pages

Comment: @db306 Your solution is risky. pages may not crawl In long-term.